Distribution function of the sum of independent variables.
Suppose $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are two independent random variables , $X_2$ and $Y_2$ are two independent random variables , if $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same distribution function,$Y_1$ and $Y_2$ have the same distribution function.
Whether $X_1+Y_1$ have the same distribution function with $X_2+Y_2$?
I know that this conclusion is correct for normal distribution, so I wonder if this is true for general distribution.

Yes, and best way to prove this is to use characteristic functions.

Thanks a lot ?By the way,Whether it’s true for a continuous function g(X,Y)?

Yes, $(X_1,Y_1)$ has same joint distribution as $(X_2,Y_2)$ has, so $g(X_1,Y_1)$ has same  distribution as $g(X_2,Y_2)$ for any Borel measurable function $g$.
